# Android Youtube api player stops continuously

Tags: android, video, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm using youtube api player to play videos in my application.

```
    youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_view, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

    playerStateChangeListener = new MyPlayerStateChangeListener();
    playbackEventListener = new MyPlaybackEventListener();

    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(ApplicationConstants.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            mplayer = player;
            player.setFullscreen(false);
            player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
            player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);
            player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);
            if (!wasRestored) {
                player.cueVideo(url); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        }
```

I'm changing the player dimes on device configuration changes,

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    int config = newConfig.orientation;
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mYoutubeView.getLayoutParams();
    switch (config){
        case  Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE :
            mplayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);
            params.height = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 300,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            params.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ;//(int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 375,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            mYoutubeView.setLayoutParams(params);
            break;
        case  Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT :
            params.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            params.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            mYoutubeView.setLayoutParams(params);
            break;
    }
}
```

using this flag i can stop the continuous stop in player api, `player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);`

but the issue is,

1. while playing a video if user minimize the application (pressing device home button) and change the device font size in setting ->font-size
2. reopen the minimized, go to a video and changed the orientation to horizontal, it will display the previous video which i was playing before minimizing the application.
3. any how this behavior can be avoid if i removed `player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);` flag, but then the video will stops continuously.

Answer (score 2):

Try using loadVideo() instead of cueVideo()